# Inexplicable behavior in algorithm that should create 4 lists based on the items of a list

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, list

The entire program is a coursework based on the classic snake game - we have a list that stores the sequence of the for directions - up, down, left right. Thus far everything is tested and works correct. The next part is a procedure that creates 4 lists - one for each direction, using the list of the directions, for example - if we have input up, up, left, left, right, left, right, up, we have two ups next to each other and then one separate, which will result in the up list storing the values 2, 1. However, the last element is not stored and some elements are stored in the wrong lists. Here is the original code of the procedure:

```
void separate() {
point current=headSnake;
int count=0;
int lastMove=5;
do{
    if (lastMove == current->value){
    count++;
    }
    else {
        switch(lastMove){
        case UP:addToList(count,headUp);break;
        case RIGHT:addToList(count,headRight);break;
        case DOWN:addToList(count,headDown);break;
        case LEFT:addToList(count,headLeft);break;
        }

        count=1;
        lastMove=current->value;
        }   
    current=current->next; 
}while (current);
}
```

UP, RIGHT, DOWN and LEFT are predefined constants, equaling 0, 1, 2 and 3. headSnake, headUp, headRight, headDown and headLeft point to the first elements of the corresponding lists. `point` is a `typedef` of `ListElem*`, which is a `struct`. `addToList(int, point)` is a procedure that is confirmed to work and it adds the integer as a last element to the list which's head we are providing as a second argument.

The following behavior we cannot explain:

with input:

```
up up left left right left right down right right
```

the procedure outputs `up: 2 ;right: 1, 1, 1; down: 1, 2; left: 2;`
which is clearly wrong. Where is the mistake in the algorithm?

Comment: use a debugger to follow execution for your example input?

Comment: +1 for the debugger. Another thing you can do is to start with a much simpler input (say `up`) and then build up from that. The bug spotted by Mario Stoilov would have been revealed clearly with such small input.

Answer (score 0):

If your input ends in several equal elements (example: `up down right right`) you will not reach the else statement for the last two rights, since you only enter it when your input **changes** (and not when it actually runs out). You should add a check for when your input ends, something like this:

```
point current=headSnake;
    int count=0;
    int lastMove=5;
    do
    {
        if (lastMove == current->value)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else 
        {
            saveMove(lastMove, count);
            count=1;
            lastMove=current->value;
        }

        if(!current->next)
        {
            saveMove(current, count);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            current=current->next;
        }

    }
    while (true);// true or current - same result

    public void saveMove(point move, int count)
    {
        switch(move)
            {
                case UP:addToList(count,headUp);break;
                case RIGHT:addToList(count,headRight);break;
                case DOWN:addToList(count,headDown);break;
                case LEFT:addToList(count,headLeft);break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a repeating move at the end, a single one wouldn't be taken into account either. But this alone is not enough to explain all the weirdness of the output.

Comment: actually if it ends in a single the `if` clause would be false, since current is `null` (false, or whatever the end points to) and `lastMove` isn't, so the `else` will be entered. But the other wierdness... well he has a debugger for that

Comment: The `if` clause is not evaluated when `current` is `null` (and that's a good thing), since the loop exits first.